# How does rtabmap fuse wheel odometry with visual odometry?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, kinect, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I set up my robot with turtlebot and kinect and excute rtabmap.

-- http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot

I hid the image of the Kinect sensor and moved the turtlebot.

And I moved the turtlebot to calculate the travel distance only with the kinect image.

I think the rtabmap algorithm is internally fusing image information and wheel odometry.

How are you fusing?

And do you have your own paper about fusing wheel odometry and viusal odometry?

Thank you ^ ^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251369/how-does-rtabmap-fuse-wheel-odometry-with-visual-odometry?/) by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

rtabmap doesn't fuse wheel odometry and visual odometry. There is only one odometry input to rtabmap node (so one or the other can be used). If you want to fuse odometries, look at the [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html) package for example, then use its odometrry output as the odometry input of rtabmap.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on 2017-01-11**:
I have question.

Where does RTABMAP use the incoming odometry?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-12**:
Some examples here: http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot

**Comment by [JunJun](https://answers.ros.org/users/27022/junjun/) on 2017-01-12**:
hmm i want to know how rtabmap algorithm use internally odometry.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-01-12**:
The map's graph has two kinds of links: odometry and loop closure. Odometry is used to set the transform between two consecutive nodes added to map's graph.

**Comment by [an99990](https://answers.ros.org/users/110646/an99990/) on 2022-07-14**:
how does one would use your visual odometry and fuse it with wheel odometry ? if my odom_topic is my wheel odometry it means that theres no visual odometry done ? ty

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2022-10-09**:
rtabmap node doesn't do odometry, it just consumes it. If you don't start `rgbd_odometry` or `stereo_odometry` nodes, you can feed rtabmap directly with your own odom topic.